# Dotconnect for PostgreSQL not showing up in Data Sources

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, dotconnect

I want to connect to an existing postgresql database using dotconnect

The tutorial is here : http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/tutorial_ef.html

The only problem is when I select Generate from database, I don't have the PostgreSQL option anywhere in data sources(like in the tutorial) . I installed the express version of dot connect and it doesn't show up anywhere. How do I use it?

Should I get the 30 day trial or is there a way to work with the Express version?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework support is not available in Express Edition of dotConnect for PostgreSQL. Please refer to http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/editions.html . We recommend you to install dotConnect for PostgreSQL Professional Trial ( http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/download.html ) - this installation package includes Entity Framework support.